# Faster alternative to Tensorflows tf.einsum()

Tags: tensorflow

I need to compute the following tensor with three-dimensional tensors x,y

```
tf.einsum("ijk,ljk->ilj",x,y)
```

Unfortunately, this is pretty slow. Is there any way to rewrite this using only matmul operations that I didn't think of?

Answer (score 0):

You can (implicitely) broadcast `x` to the shape `iljk` and `y` to the shape `ilkj`.
Then it is possible to use `tf.matmul()` to get shape `iljj` and tf.sum() for eliminating one `j`.
The resulting shape then is `ilj`.

```
x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1)

y = tf.transpose(y, [0,2,1])
y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=0)

tf.sum(tf.matmul(x, y), axis=-2)
```

However, I dont think that this would be faster since you get a 4D tensor here.

Comment: ```tf.einsum``` will be slow because of the implicit ```tf.transpose``` that induces a copy of the tensor. Having a transpose here would be bad.